# jCarousel connected to a lightbox plugin for wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, lightbox, jcarousel

I'm looking for a simple Wordpress plugin that loads up the thumbnails (from a gallery) inside a jcarousel and links them to the full images via lightbox. It can be free or not. :)

Could you please help me out with a link or two?

**Thanks**!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grab Fancybox for Wordpress:

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/fancybox-for-wordpress/

Then add `class="fancybox"` to your jCarousel image tags.

If you don't want to hand code in the jcarousel.
Try Slidesjs: http://slidesjs.com/

IT HAS A WORDPRESS PLUGINT TOO! https://github.com/sico/Slides-for-Wordpress

Comment: Thank you! I'll try it out now. But I need a jCarousel that loads up the thumbnails from the gallery so I don't write them manually.